# Changing list position of multiple specific factors

Tags: r

There's lot of info out there about how to reorder lists, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific question:

Suppose the following list of factors, which is sorted:

```
x <- factor(c(1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 8, 10, 34))
x

Levels: 1 3 4 7 8 10 34
```

Now suppose I like the order of these factors, EXCEPT I want to bring two of the factors to the front, a shift everything else down, e.g.:

```
Levels: 10 7 1 3 4 8 34     # order is preserved, except 10 and 7 are moved to front
```

I know with a small list that it's possible to manually change the order, like this:

```
factor(x, levels = c(10, 7, 1, 3, 4, 8, 34))

x
Levels: 10 7 1 3 4 8 34
```

But in my case, I'm working with a large list of factors where it is impractical to manually sort. Also, this list of factors changes, so I'd like to do this more dynamically.

So, I'm looking for a way that I can move the position of specified factors, while preserving the order of everything else in the list, without explicitly referencing all the other list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `relevel`

```
relevel(x, "10")
#[1] 1  4  3  7  4  8  10 34
#Levels: 10 1 3 4 7 8 34
```

---

If we need to relevel multiple levels

```
forcats::fct_relevel(x, c(10, 7))
#[1] 1  4  3  7  4  8  10 34
#Levels: 10 7 1 3 4 8 34
```

The position can also be changed

```
forcats::fct_relevel(x, c(10, 7), after = 3)
#[1] 1  4  3  7  4  8  10 34
#Levels: 1 3 4 10 7 8 34
```

The position can also be at the end

```
forcats::fct_relevel(x, c(10, 7), after = Inf)
#[1] 1  4  3  7  4  8  10 34
#Levels: 1 3 4 8 34 10 7
```

Comment: Sorry, after I pushed 'submit' I realized I really need the ability to push multiple factors to the front (and I'm already aware of this approach to bringing a single factor to the front)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `setdiff`

```
x <- factor(c(1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 8, 10, 34))
L1 = levels(x)
ToMove = c("10","7")
L2 = c(ToMove, setdiff(L1, ToMove))
x <- factor(x, levels=L2)
levels(x)
[1] "10" "7"  "1"  "3"  "4"  "8"  "34"
```